# Reference request for perfection of schemes over finite fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, finite-fields, schemes

I am currently reading a paper from 2021 which uses "perfection" of schemes over finite fields. If $X$ is such a scheme over $\mathbb F_q$, the associated perfection is denoted by $X^{\mathrm{perf}}$. The whole process is used without reference, so that the construction seems to be well-known in that area of algebraic geometry. However it is the first time that I encounter this.

Would somebody understand what kind of space $X^{\mathrm{perf}}$ is, and could recommend some material to learn more on the perfection process?

Comment: A friend recommended [Bertapelle & Gonzales-Aviles' reference paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.02060.pdf) to me a while back - maybe you will also find it useful.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for the reference, I also stumbled upon this paper with a Google search. However, to my understanding it looks like the authors mainly focus on another kind of perfection, denoted by $X^{\mathrm{pf}}$, which seems to differ from $X^{\mathrm{perf}}$ by taking a limit in the other direction, according to Remark 4.8. Maybe I ought to take a look at Fontaine's and Scholze's works which are cited in this Remark.

Comment: Which definition of perfection do you mean? If you mean the limit over Frobenius then looking at the appendix to Zhu’s Annals paper is a good place to read about it.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you for the reference, it looks perfect ! (no pun intended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to get this off of the unaswered list, a good place to start reading about this topic is Appendix A of the following paper.

Zhu, X., 2017. Affine Grassmannians and the geometric Satake in mixed characteristic. Annals of Mathematics, 185(2), pp.403-492.